# How can I protect a portion of my app from certain users (ie. one of the tabbed views can only be seen by certain users)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I am building my first iOS app (other than just samples etc) that I will try to put on the app store.  I will make this for iPhone/ipad and using iOS 5.0.

I was thinking of having my app have tabbed views.  I will have a basic users and a "member" user.  The member user would have access to a feature/view/data that a basic user does not.  I am looking for two things.  One, some ideas on a best way to protect/hide this from the basic user and two, some technical code help too on how to do it.  I have had an idea that I could possibly have one pin code that all members know or even do an id/password where I keep that info in a plist or something and then I could in `viewdidload` (maybe?) cause a modal view to come up and challenge the person before letting them see the view/data.

Looking for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this delegate method, then use logic to decide whether to return YES or NO:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
Parameters
tabBarController
The tab bar controller containing viewController.
viewController
The view controller belonging to the tab that was tapped by the user.
Return Value
YES if the view controller’s tab should be selected or NO if the current tab should remain active.

Discussion
The tab bar controller calls this method in response to the user tapping a tab bar item. You can use this method to dynamically decide whether a given tab should be made the active tab.
```

Comment: I will look into this as it sounds like what I was trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: If in the end this does it for you, it would be great if you would tap the check mark and select this answer.

Comment: This did help me with the code. I still have to figure out how to challenge the user to see if they are a member.  The members only section will have names and email address of members and so only members should see it so I do need to protect it from normal "public/basic/non member" user. So some kind of pin or id/password or I have also thought if the member supplies their name and member number I can check that against the member list which I can have as a plist or something in my app and let them see the view if they have the correct info.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend a preset password approach. You will find the baked-in username and password posted on message boards almost instantly. You will want to use either a web-service for authentication or have it be an in-app purchase.

Comment: I am not making anyone buy the app. The app is free in fact. This app is for a church and non members can see certain content and a member can see all content. So I just need to protect certain data from a non member of the church.

Comment: I will lookup the built in id/password system to see if that will work. thanks.

Comment: @DirectX I see, if you don't care if non-members see the members only section, then security doesn't matter. Having a username/password system doesn't make much sense. Just have a switch that turns on the members information.

Comment: No, I do care.  The members only section will have names and email address of members and so only members should see it so I do need to protect it from normal "public/basic/non member" user.  So some kind of pin or id/password or I have also thought if the member supplies their name and member number I can check that against the member list which I can have as a plist or something in my app and let them see the view if they have the correct info.

Comment: @DirectX If you are concerned about security, then you should take security seriously. Remote authentication is not that hard to implement and allows you to monitor which user are logging in, disable compromised accounts, and to reset password for people who have forgotten. Bad security can be worse than no security.